# Download OSX Dictionary files

Tags: discussion, resources

I just got a new Mac a few weeks ago running Moutain Lion (10.8), and I've noticed that they changed the available Japanese dictionaries that are included in the `Dictionary.app` application.  The new ones are `ウィズダム英和・和英辞典` and `スーパー大辞林`.

I know the previous version of the OS (Lion - 10.7) had the `プログレッシブ英和・和英辞典` included, and I'd really like to get that back on my new machine.  It seems the dictionaries are just stored in the `/Library/Dictionaries/` folder.

Does anyone know if/where these dictionaries are downloadable?  Are they open-source, open/standard format files, or are they in a proprietary format for `Dictionary.app`?

---

**Update**: I was able to straight-up copy the files from a co-worker's 10.7 (10.6?) Mac over to mine, and the `Dictionary.app` application picked them up when I restarted it.

I'd still like to know though, if these are downloadable somewhere in the case where one doesn't have access to an older version of the OS.

Comment: I think they're commercial dictionaries, not free, and that you get them because Apple paid for them.  I'm not sure you can download them for free.